# How to add a div to KnpMenu (Symfony2.1)

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

I would like to make a drowdown box whenever someone hovers over a menu button, im generating the menu with the KnpMenuBundle.

What i would like to get is a structure like this:

```
<lu>
    <li><a>...</a></li>
    <li>
        <a>...</a>
        <div>...</div>
    </li>
    <li><a>...</a></li>
<lu>
```

If possible i would like to render a controller from inside the div.

Can this be done?

If i missed something in the documentation please post a link because i have been searching for hours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, and I once did exactly this, but whether this sort of thing should be done using KnpMenuBundle I'm not too sure! Anyway, I achieved this by defining my MenuBuilder class as a service and injecting the @templating service. This doesn't call a controller action as you mentioned, but allows you to render any template you wish...

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Knp\Menu\ItemInterface
 */
protected function createUserMenuLoggedOut(Request $request)
{
    $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');

    $signInItem = $menu->addChild('Sign in', array('route' => 'fos_user_security_login'));
    $signInItem
        ->setLinkAttributes(array(
            'id' => 'sign-in-link',
            'class' => 'dropdown-toggle',
            'data-toggle' => 'dropdown',
            'data-target' => '#signin'
        ))
        ->setAttributes(array(
            'id' => 'signin',
            'class' => 'dropdown'
        ))
    ;

    // THIS IS THE LINE YOU'RE INTERESTED IN
    $signInItem->addChild($this->templating->render('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:Security:login_options.html.twig'));

    // more menu items...

    return $menu;
}
```

If I recall correctly, I think this ended up wrapping the template in an additional `<ul>...</ul>` but this didn't cause much of a problem after a bit of styling.

Comment: Thanks i will try i right now. Also i just found this: [github example](https://gist.github.com/2278437), might be usefull for other. And if this should not be done KnpMenuBundle what do you use for your menus?

Comment: That would be an example of when I **would** use KnpMenuBundle, because it is rendering a submenu (e.g. `<ul><li>Parent<ul><li>Child 1</li><li>Child 2</li></ul></li><!-- more top-level menu items... --></ul>`) for a top-level menu item. If I find myself having to hack the menu too much to control the HTML output I tend to just make it out of good, old-fashioned twig templates.